# Will not let me put attach methods next to variables

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am trying to search a div to access things and it will not let me attach them, I've looked it up but even when i bring it into Visual Studio, it doesn't work correctly.
edit: to clarify im talking about the last section of code, i provided the rest of it for context.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://youtube.com')

searchBox= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="xv-search-form"]/div/div/input')
searchBox.send_keys('cat videos')

clickSearch = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="xv-search-form"]/div/div/span/button')
clickSearch.click()

video=driver.find_element_by_id('main')
for main in video:
title = video.find_elements_by_class_name('title')
print(title.text)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Likely the issue is with indentation in that last block. You need to indent on lines after the `for` in order to include them in the loop. So your code should probably be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://youtube.com')

searchBox= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="xv-search-form"]/div/div/input')
searchBox.send_keys('cat videos')

clickSearch = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="xv-search-form"]/div/div/span/button')
clickSearch.click()

video=driver.find_element_by_id('main')
for main in video:
    title = video.find_elements_by_class_name('title')
    print(title.text)
```

Also, I notice this loop is pointless... `video` will only ever have length 1 so the loop will run only once. Anyway, you only reference `video` in the loop, not `main`. Finally, you are setting `title = video.find_elements()`, which will return an array. So `title.text` will not work. So there are a few problems here. Try cleaning this up and see how things go. Perhaps you meant something like:

```
main=driver.find_elements_by_id('main')
for main in video:
    title = video.find_element_by_class_name('title')
    print(title.text)
```

Or maybe

```
main=driver.find_elements_by_id('main')
for main in video:
    titles = video.find_elements_by_class_name('title')
    for title in titles:
        print(title.text)
```